# Ruby Regex optimization

Tags: ruby, regex, optimization

Regex newbie here. I have a regular expression that matches Windows pathnames and UNC paths, terminated by '\'.

Working examples:

```
c:\windows\
c:\
\\server\share\
\\server\sh are\
```

Invalid:

```
c:\windows
\\server
\\server\share
\\server\ share \
```

However, it works as expected (at least i hope so), but it's pretty unreadable and not very performant, so any tips for optimization are greatly appreciated...

```
/\A(
  ([a-z]:\\(([a-zA-Z0-9äöüÄÖÜß_.$]+|[a-zA-Z0-9äöüÄÖÜß_.$]+[a-zA-Z0-9äöüÄÖÜß_.$\ ]*[a-zA-Z0-9äöüÄÖÜß_.$]+)\\)*)|
  (\\\\(([a-zA-Z0-9äöüÄÖÜß_.$]+|[a-zA-Z0-9äöüÄÖÜß_.$]+[a-zA-Z0-9äöüÄÖÜß_.$\ ]*[a-zA-Z0-9äöüÄÖÜß_.$]+)\\)+(([a-zA-Z0-9äöüÄÖÜß_.$]+|
  [a-zA-Z0-9äöüÄÖÜß_.$]+[a-zA-Z0-9äöüÄÖÜß_.$\ ]*[a-zA-Z0-9äöüÄÖÜß_.$]+)\\)+)
)\z/
```

Comment: You're missing out on an enormous number of valid filenames (there are lots of other characters allowed) - isn't that a problem? And you're allowing many invalid filenames (for example `con.txt`). What exactly are you planning to do? Checking for validity?

Comment: Sorry for the lack of information on this, i'm using Ruby 1.9 any you are right, i'm trying to check for validity...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In Ruby 1.9, the following should work:

```
if subject =~ 
    /\A(?:(?!.*\\(?:con|prn|aux|nul|com\d|lpt\d)\\)  # exclude invalid names
    (?:                                              # Either match        
     [a-z]:\\                                        # drive letter 
    |                                                # or
     \\\\(?:[^\\\/:*?"<>|\s]+\\){2}                  # UNC share name
    )                                                # End of alternation
    (?:                                              # Try to match:
     (?!\s)                                          # (Assert no starting space)
     [^\\\/:*?"<>|\r\n]+                             # a valid directory name
     (?<!\s)                                         # (Assert no ending space)
     \\                                              # backslash
    )*                                               # repeat as needed
    )\Z/mix
    # Successful match
else
    # Match attempt failed
end
```

Comment: This allows UNC paths without share names (\\server\\), but i'll get this to work and it looks way cleaner than my regzilla, thanks...

Comment: Ah, ok, shouldn't they be allowed? No problem.

Comment: Hmm, this still allows \\server\. Isn't something like (pseudocode): if unc share at least one valid directory name required needed?

Comment: You're right, sorry. Now it shouldn't do this any more. Spaces are not permitted in server and share names, is that correct?

Comment: I'm not sure about that, afair they are permitted for share names, but spaces in servernames are filled with '-', e.g. '\\ser-ver\my share\', i'll have to look this up. However, thanks again for your answer...